# Is there a way to access local static resource from a managed package

Tags: managed-package, static-resources

I have managed package which has a VF page which displays some images. I need someway for users in the installed environment to change the images to suit their requirements.

I certainly know that we cant edit the static resource which is part of managed package. So my thought process was to allow users to upload their own static resource and give the name of that static resource in custom setting and i would dynamically bind the static resource name.

I am able to dynamically bind the static resource name in my controller and display the images in the VF page. But this only works on the developed environment and doesnt work  on the installed environment.

Any thoughts what could be reason why the images not appearing in installed env

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found it the hard way, the static resource needs to be public. 
Had defined it as private in the installed env.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you did this? I'm trying to do this, but the local resource is not available when I query for it...how did you access the resource and display it?