# Does Loading Static Resource Dynamically through URL pass the Salesforce AppExchange Security Review

Tags: appexchange, static-resources, security-review, lightning-components, second-generation-packaging

We have created a Second Generation Managed Package and in it we need to load the static resource which is uploaded by the Subscriber (the one who installs the package).

We have loaded the static resource using the URL approach (`/resource[/timestamp]/YourStaticResourceName`) mentioned in this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45387/accessing-local-static-resources-from-a-managed-package/45395#45395)

And In one LWC Component, we have a requirement of Custom Datatype of Lightning Datatable. So we have used a Custom Component for Custom Datatype and for passing data from Custom Component to our Lightning Datatable Component we have used Custom Event with bubbles and composable parameters set as true and In the Datatable Event Handler, we have stopped the event propagation, so that the custom event doesn't pass or propagate behind the Datatable Component and stays in the Managed Package Boundary.

Will these approaches pass the Salesforce AppExchange Security Review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We allow customization in our package using similar static resource upload, and naming via a setting. We don't manually generate the URL, using `URLFOR` instead. But, regardless, this should not cause any issues with security review.

As to the LWC event propagation, AFAIK what you have done will not cause any security review issues (fairly sure we have a couple of places we do similar). If you are concerned, the best approach is to explicitly cover this event usage pattern in your false positive documentation provided as part of your submission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Phil, We have used Custom Event with bubbles and composable parameters set as true, does this impact security review in anyway. I have edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: It would have been best to cover that in a separate question, TBH, but I've updated my answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Phil.

Comment: Hi @Phil W, We want to make our Managed Package licensed, So we have few doubts regarding the licenses and permission sets. I have asked a question.  Could you please us. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/412796/how-does-permission-sets-works-against-licenses-of-managed-package

Answer (score 0):

You should not have any issues with this pattern. If it's flagged, file a case in partner portal as this is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robert, We have used Custom Event with bubbles and composable parameters set as true, does this impact security review in anyway. I have edited the question. Please check it.

Comment: Yeah, you can bubble/compose events, just load the resource in your namespace as you are doing.

Comment: Thanks Robert, we are loading the resource in our manage package codes only i.e in our Namespace only.